# Solve $\sin a =\sin x+\sin y, \cos a =\cos x+\cos y$ for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I saw this on quora.

Solve

$\begin{array}\\
\sin a
&=\sin x+\sin y\\
\cos a
&=\cos x+\cos y\\
\end{array}
$

for $x$ and $y$
in terms of
$a$.

Here is my solution.

My question:
is there a better way
of solving this?

My answer is
$y
=a+\frac{\pi}{3}
$
and
$x
=a-\frac{\pi}{3}
$.

Squaring and adding,
$1
= 2+2\sin(x)\sin(y)+2\cos(x)\cos(y)
$
or
$\cos(x-y)
=-\frac12
$
so
$x-y
=\pm\frac{2\pi}{3}
$
so either
$x
=y+\frac{2\pi}{3}
$
or
$x
=y-\frac{2\pi}{3}
$.

(I'm not worrying about the
$2 k\pi$
for now.)

Substituting
$x
=y+\frac{2\pi}{3}
$
in the first,

$\begin{array}\\
\sin a
&=\sin x+\sin y\\
&=\sin(y+\frac{2\pi}{3})+\sin y\\
&=\sin(y)\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})+\cos(y)\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})+\sin y\\
&=-\frac12\sin(y)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(y)+\sin y\\
&=\frac12\sin(y)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(y)\\
&=\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})\sin(y)+\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})\cos(y)\\
&=\cos(y-\frac{\pi}{6})\\
&=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-(y-\frac{\pi}{6}))
\qquad\text{(using } \cos(z)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-z))\\
&=\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}-y)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$y
=-a+\frac{2\pi}{3}
$
and
$x
=y+\frac{2\pi}{3}
=-a+\frac{4\pi}{3}
$.

Checking,

$\begin{array}\\
\sin x+\sin y
=\sin(a)\\
\cos x+\cos y
=-\cos(a)\\
\end{array}
$

so this doesn't work!!!

Note:
the checking was done by
Wolfram Alpha.

Try the other solution.

Substituting
$x
=y-\frac{2\pi}{3}
$
in the first,

$\begin{array}\\
\sin a
&=\sin x+\sin y\\
&=\sin(y-\frac{2\pi}{3})+\sin y\\
&=\sin(y)\cos(-\frac{2\pi}{3})+\cos(y)\sin(-\frac{2\pi}{3})+\sin y\\
&=-\frac12\sin(y)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(y)+\sin y\\
&=\frac12\sin(y)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(y)\\
&=\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})\sin(y)-\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})\cos(y)\\
&=-\cos(y+\frac{\pi}{6})\\
&=-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-(y+\frac{\pi}{6}))\\
&=-\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-y)\\
&=\sin(y-\frac{\pi}{3})\\
\end{array}
$

so
$y
=a+\frac{\pi}{3}
$
and
$x
=y-\frac{2\pi}{3}
=a-\frac{\pi}{3}
$.

Upon checking,
this works.

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ play symmetric roles in the equations and your answers are not symmetric, you're definitely missing something.

Comment: Related: [Vertices of equilateral triangle inscribed in the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201100/vertices-of-equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-the-unit-circle) with $z_1=\operatorname{cis}(x)$, $z_2=\operatorname{cis}(y)$, $z_3=\operatorname{cis}(a+\pi)$.

Comment: It is not true that if $\sin A=\sin B$, then $A=B$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1912849/42969. The points $\cos(x) + i \sin(x)$, $\cos(y) + i \sin(y)$, and $\cos(-a) + i \sin(-a)$ form an equilateral triangle with vertices on the unit circle.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201100/42969

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I would recommend you to divide both equations in order to get:
\begin{align*}
\tan(a) = \frac{\sin(x) + \sin(y)}{\cos(x) + \cos(y)} & = \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x - y}{2}\right)}{2\cos\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x - y}{2}\right)} = \tan\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Based on it, can you proceed from here?